# Reading google sheets and displaying contents in Dialogflow using external webhook

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to build a `bot` which will read contents from `google sheets` and reply the user for her query in `Dialogflow`. I am using an external fulfillment for this.

I am unable to read the contents and display the results.

I am new to `node.js` and not fully cognizant with `async` functions.

Input will be " Tell me about Training Events" and the output will be  those events which are Scheduled . I have written the Intent and enabled fulfillment for the Intent.
[image]

*****The code is below:*****

```
const express = require('express')

const http = require('http')

//require('dotenv').config()
const df = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const app = express()
//const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const port = 3000

const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const creds = require('./test_bot_key3.json');


app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Server is working.')
})

 app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(` Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`)
 })
 


app.post('/', (req,res)=>{

   const agent = new df.WebhookClient({
        request:req,
        response:res

    });


 function greetings(agent){

    agent.add("Hi there! I am test Bot!!!");
 }

 function timing(agent){
   accessSpreadsheet(agent); //accessSpreadSheet is an async function
    }



async function accessSpreadsheet(agent){

    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('xyz');//here i have put ID of Google Spread Sheet

    await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);//authenticating the passed credentials

    const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)(); //getting information of google sheets

    const sheet = info.worksheets[0];

    const rows = await promisify(sheet. getRows)({
    //offset:1
    query: 'plan = Scheduled'  //selecting those rows where plan is Scheduled
    
    });

    
    rows.forEach(row=> { //reading all rows from google sheets which are scheduled

     agent.add(`Serial Num: ${dbs.serialnum}`); //adding agent.add --- I think we cant add multiple //agent.add but I am not sure how to print all these columns of a selected row in Dialogflow
     agent.add(` Event: ${dbs.dbsevent}`);
     agent.add(`Start Date: ${dbs.startdate}`);
     agent.add(`Month: ${dbs.month}`);
     agent.add(`Type: ${dbs.type}`);
     agent.add(`Plan: ${dbs.plan}`);
     agent.add(`Trainer: ${dbs.trainer}`);
     agent.add('-----------');
   
    });
   }

    //});


var intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Greetings', greetings);
intentMap.set('testTiming', timing);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);


});
```

I am getting below error:

> (node:15188) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No responses
> defined for platform: DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE

in Node.js console

and Fulfillment Status is Webhook call failed. `Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED.`

It would be great if someone could help me with the code change which will ensure that the multiple rows which pass the filter of
`plan = Scheduled`
are returned by the Fulfillment and then can be displayed by the `bot` in `Dialogflow` in `JSON` format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Here you have the [Node.js Sheets API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs). Please check it to test an authorization flow and write back sharing your findings.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jacques-Guzel Heron.. will check and revert.